# How can I debug my social security number validation code?

Tags: python

I am trying to validate a SSN, that should be in format: xxxCd1d2m1m2y1y2. "xxx" are consecutively assigned digits, "C" is the checksum digit, "dd" donates the day, "mm" the month and "yy" the year of birth.

```
c == (x1*3 + x2*7 + x3*9 + d1*5 + d2*8 + m1*4 + m2*2 + y1*1 + y2*6) % 11
```

The number should have exactly 10 digits (not more or less). Of course **c** should be according to the formula and date format should be right. Here is what I've got so far:

```
from datetime import datetime

def is_valid(digit_list):
    ssn=list(digit_list)
    x1, x2, x3, c, d1, d2, m1, m2, y1, y2 = [int(digit) for digit in digit_list]
    date=digit_list[4:]

    if len(ssn) == 10 and c == (x1*3 + x2*7 + x3*9 + d1*5 + d2*8 + m1*4 + m2*2 + y1*1 + y2*6) % 11 and date==datetime.strptime(date,'%d%m%y'):
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

Example of valid number: 5446180993

Comment: So what does your code do that it needs correction?

Comment: It always prints 'False', even if i input correct number.

Comment: Have you tried looking at each condition in your if and checking out which one fails? (This is also known as debugging)

Comment: I am pretty sure it is datetime part, but I don't really know how to correct that properly, so it would validate the date.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow readers are happy to help, but question posters still need to do the work. Questions that are of the form "please fix it for me" will be heavily downvoted, even if it wasn't the intention of the poster to request free work.

Answer (score 0):

`date == datetime.strptime(date,'%d%m%y')` will never work.  `datetime.strptime` returns a `datetime.datetime` instance and `date` is a six character string.

If you are trying to validate that the last six characters are a valid date, you should parse the portions of the date as integers and pass them to [datetime.date](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) instead.  It will raise a `ValueError` if the values are non-sensical.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to validate that the last 6 digits are date (in correct format).